# Prove that if matrix $B$ is nilpotent, then the determinant is zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ be a matrix of size $n \times n$

(1) $B$ is called nilpotent if $\exists k \in\mathbb{N}$ so that
$B_k$ is the zero matrix. Prove that if the matrix $B$ is nilpotent, then the determinant of $B = 0$.

(2) $B$ is called skew-symmetric if its transpose is equal
to $−B$. Lets assume that $B$ is skew-symmetric and invertible. Show that $n$ is even.

From my understanding, a nilpotent is a matrix $N$ such that the eigenvalues of the matrix are all zero. I was thinking that I need to link this definition to be able to prove that the determinant of the matrix is zero. Furthermore, in part (2), I am completely confused where to begin. I am not sure how to prove that $n$ is even.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint for $(1)$: $\text{det}(XY) = \text{det}(X)\text{det}(Y)$. Hint for $(2)$: complex eigenvalues of real matrices come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: "...the eigenvalues of the matrix are all zero". So if at least *one* eigenvalue of a matrix is zero then the determinant is...

Comment: $B$ is called nilpotent if $\exists k\in\Bbb N$ such that $B^k = \underbrace{B\times B\times \cdots \times B}_{k~\text{times}}$ is the zero matrix.  Super script, not subscript.

Comment: As for your "attempt" and thoughts at the bottom.  You say "*From my understanding, a nilpotent (matrix) is a matrix such that the eigenvalues of the matrix are all zero.*"  Regardless of whether or not that is true, that is not the *definition* you are given in the problem.  You should use the *definition* if at all possible.  If you use a different definition, then you must also prove that the other definition is equivalent or cite that result if it were proven in class or in your textbook.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Note: The determinant is 0 $\iff$ The matrix is not invertible

So it suffices to show that if the matrix is nilpotent then the matrix is not invertible

Assume the matrix, $B$, is nilpotent and is invertible.

Then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B^n=0$ and some $B^{-1}$ such that $BB^{-1}=1$

$$B^n=0$$
$$B^n(B^{-1})^n=(0)(B^{-1})^n$$
$$B^nB^{-n}=0$$
$$1=0$$

Hence $1=0$ and we have reached a contradiction. Therefore, if a matrix is nilpotent then it is not invertible, hence, it is determinant 0.

Note: $0$ and $1$ here refer to the zero and identity matrix respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, $B=-B^t$ implies $$\det B=\det (-B^t)=(-1)^n \det B^t=(-1)^n \det B$$ and $\det B \neq 0$, so $1=(-1)^n$. The latter is happen only when $n$ is even

Comment: I don't quite understand your final line in this proof ("The latter is happen only when n is even"). What exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Don't worry, I completely understand, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For square matrices $A,B$ of equal size over a commutative ring with unity: $\det (AB) = \det(A)\cdot\det(B)$.
In your case, the matrix $B$ is nilpotent and so $B^k=0$ (zero matrix) for some $k\geq 1$.
Then $0=\det(0) = \det (B^k) = \det(B)^k$.
If the ring has no zero divisors, $\det(B)=0$ as required.